# Nginx vhosts per path

Tags: nginx, config, vhosts

How do I setup nginx conf so that "blah.com/website1" and "blah.com/website2" etc can point to separate websites that are running on the machine (vhost?)?
E.g. localhost:3000 is website1 and localhost:3001 is website2.
So when a user points their browser at blah.com/website1 they access the website localhost:3000 and localhost:3001 for website2?

I've tried a reverse proxy but that can't map paths like "blah.com/website1" and only seems to handle the server name of "blah.com".

Update:
So I've tried a config like this to use reverse proxy, but all assests on the website are not loading as they are trying to load from the domain's root. Probably because it's not a vhost? The page loads but assets are trying to load and 404ing, e.g: http://blah.com/static/css/styles.css

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name blah.com;

    location /website1/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
    }
```

}

Comment: You need to expand your question. What have you tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: If you need the assets to be served from blah.com/website1 you need to rewrite those links on the page. The NGINX sub filter module can help with that: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html